# infinite Scroll with Magnific Popup callback

Tags: jquery, callback, infinite-scroll, magnific-popup

I'm using Infinite scroll and Magnific Popup.

The popup works on the content which is 'page 1' but fails after that. I've attempted to use a callback for MagnificPopup within the infiniteScroll call.

```
$grid.infiniteScroll({
path: '.pagination__next',
append: '.grid__item',
outlayer: msnry,
status: '.page-load-status',
}, function( newElements ) {
  $('.open-pop').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
  fixedContentPos: false,
   gallery: {
   enabled: true,
   navigateByImgClick: false,
   }
 });

 });
```

My question is similar to this [Magnific popup and infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761192/magnific-popup-and-infinite-scrolling), which I've unsuccessfully tried to implement.

Potentially an added complication is I'm using Masonry. This is my full code:

```
// init Masonry

var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
 itemSelector: 'none', // select none at first
 columnWidth: '.grid__col-sizer',
 gutter: 26,
 percentPosition: true,
 stagger: 30,
 // nicer reveal transition
 visibleStyle: { transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 },
 hiddenStyle: { transform: 'translateY(100px)', opacity: 0 },
});

// get Masonry instance
var msnry = $grid.data('masonry');

// initial items reveal
$grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
$grid.removeClass('are-images-unloaded');
$grid.masonry( 'option', { itemSelector: '.grid__item' });
var $items = $grid.find('.grid__item');
$grid.masonry( 'appended', $items );
});

$grid.infiniteScroll({
path: '.pagination__next',
append: '.grid__item',
outlayer: msnry,
status: '.page-load-status',
}, function( newElements ) {
 $('.open-pop').magnificPopup({
 type: 'inline',
 mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
 fixedContentPos: false,
 gallery: {
  enabled: true,
  navigateByImgClick: false,
 }
});

});
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo fiddle? I assume that your callback event is not proper. Why don't you try adding callback using onInit `onInit: function() { this.on( 'append', function() {...}) }`

Comment: Using OnInit did the trick, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @Developer107 you should post this as an answer, so that OP can close the question.

Comment: @bhansa Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onInit` event for callback function.

```
onInit: function() { this.on( 'append', function() {...}) }
```